# Query "Group By" multiple items

Tags: php, sql

I have 4 columns of info.

```
         Team Name   GameID   TYPE    Total

         Santa Rosa    71      A       15
         CN            71      A       17
         CN            83      B       22
         CN            83      C       5
         Santa Rosa    72      D       87
```

I want to group by GameID, Team Name, then sum total, but I want to list Type like this:
A,B,C

for Query, I am able to Sum(total), then group by team name, game id......but only returns 1 "Type" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do (if it's ok for you) is this

```
SELECT GameID, `Team name`, SUM(Total) AS tot, GROUP_CONCAT(`TYPE`) AS types
FROM your_table
GROUP BY GameID, `Team name`
```

Comment: @user1079804: as you're new here at SO, I remember you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if you think it solved or helped to solve your problem. :)

Comment: I clicked the yes, was helpful button, is there any other?

Comment: @user1079804: in my previous comment there's a link that guides you :)

Comment: @user1079804: to make it short, you should click on the mark down the vote, making it green :) Thanks